# css_stylesheet_create() in libcss (error: too many arguments to function call)

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode4, struct, typedef

I´m trying to implement a C-library (libcss) in Objective C. I get an **"too many arguments to function call, expected 4, have 13"** on function **css_stylesheet_create**()

```
    code = css_stylesheet_create(CSS_LEVEL_DEFAULT, "UTF-8", "", NULL,
                             false, false, myrealloc, 0, resolve_url, 0, NULL, NULL,
                             &sheet);
```

css_stylesheet_create definition:

```
   /** 
    *  Parameter block for css_stylesheet_create() 
    */ 

    typedef struct css_stylesheet_params {
            /** ABI version of this structure */
            uint32_t params_version;


            /** The language level of the stylesheet */
            css_language_level level;
            /** The charset of the stylesheet data, or NULL to detect */
            const char *charset;
            /** URL of stylesheet */
            const char *url;
            /** Title of stylesheet */
            const char *title;

            /** Permit quirky parsing of stylesheet */
            bool allow_quirks;
            /** This stylesheet is an inline style */
            bool inline_style;

            /** URL resolution function */
            css_url_resolution_fn resolve;
            /** Client private data for resolve */
            void *resolve_pw;

            /** Import notification function */
            css_import_notification_fn import;
            /** Client private data for import */
            void *import_pw;

            /** Colour resolution function */
            css_color_resolution_fn color;
            /** Client private data for color */
            void *color_pw;

            /** Font resolution function */
            css_font_resolution_fn font;
            /** Client private data for font */
            void *font_pw;
   } css_stylesheet_params;

css_error css_stylesheet_create(const css_stylesheet_params *params,
        css_allocator_fn alloc, void *alloc_pw,
        css_stylesheet **stylesheet);
```

Comment: I edited my answer with new data. Check out and see if it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The prototype asks for 4 parameters and the call has 13 parameters!

Check this  [patch](http://www.mail-archive.com/netsurf-commits@netsurf-browser.org/msg07905.html). They are changing the `css_stylesheet_create` function altogether. ie they are embedding all parameters inside `css_stylesheet_params` thereby reducing the number of params to `css_stylesheet_create` from 13 to 4

So you need to call like this-

```
css_stylesheet_params params;

params.level = CSS_LEVEL_DEFAULT;
params.charset = "UTF-8";
params.url = "";
params.title = NULL;
params.allow_quirks = false;
params.inline_style = false;
params.resolve = resolve_url;
params.resolve_pw = NULL;
params.import = NULL;
params.import_pw = NULL;
params.color = NULL;
params.color_pw = NULL;

css_stylesheet_create(&params, myrealloc, NULL, &sheet)
```

Comment: I´m new to "pure C" so I was clueless. (The function call was from libcss example code, so I thought the code was correct. But it seems to be broken.)

Comment: @Olof Yea it happens. Example code would be outdated and there will be no mention of it and we'll be in soup :(. Its OK. There's a solution to everything :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, check out, in your function declaration you have given only 4 parameters, but you are calling the function with more than 4 arguments

```
 css_error css_stylesheet_create(const css_stylesheet_params *params,  
       css_allocator_fn alloc, void *alloc_pw,
         css_stylesheet **stylesheet);
```